# Why routes is empty in mdmsoft/yii2-admin?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-rbac

I configured **mdmsoft/yii2-admin** in yii2 basic template
but routes list is empty. why ?

[image]

**Confugrations**

```
'modules' => [
    ...
    'admin' => [
        'class' => 'mdm\admin\Module',
        'layout' => 'right-menu', // avaliable value 'left-menu', 'right-menu' and 'top-menu'
        'mainLayout' => '@app/views/layouts/main.php',
    ]
    ...
],



'components' => [
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        'defaultRoles' => ['guest']
    ]
    ...
]
```

Comment: check in the related controller the   index action

Comment: already checked in index@RouteCountroller

Comment: and then  ..  in the index action you should obatin the data  if the data are present ..  are you sure thatbthe related  data are present??

Comment: yes, all controller and action are working perfectilly

Comment: are you sure you are passing the righe data to view ??

Comment: All things are right and now showing all routes. I think this was caching issue

Comment: try clear the runtime  .directory